# Identifying Inactive Users from Previous Month’s Active User List

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Consider the following CTEs. They correctly provide me with a list of monthly active users. However, for inactive users, they return invalid user IDs. By 'inactive users' for each month (e.g., 2023-09), I am referring to users who were active during the previous month (2023-08) but were not active in the next/current month (2023-09).

```sql
WITH payments AS (
  SELECT "UserId", DATE_TRUNC('month', "PayDate") AS "Month"
  FROM "public"."Payments"
  WHERE "IsPaid" = TRUE
     AND "IsDeleted" = FALSE 
     AND "PayDate" BETWEEN {{START_DATE}} AND {{END_DATE}}
),

active_users AS (
  SELECT "Month", "UserId"
  FROM payments
  GROUP BY "Month", "UserId"
),

inactive_users AS (
  SELECT previous_month."Month" + INTERVAL '1 month' AS "Month", previous_month."UserId"
  FROM active_users AS previous_month
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM active_users AS current_month
    WHERE previous_month."UserId" = current_month."UserId"
      AND current_month."Month" = (previous_month."Month" + INTERVAL '1 month')
  )
)
```

I need the final result set to include a list of unique users and their corresponding months.

---

## Edit

```
WITH payments AS (
  SELECT "UserId", DATE_TRUNC('month', "PayDate") AS "Month"
  FROM "public"."Payments"
  WHERE "IsPaid" = TRUE
     AND "IsDeleted" = FALSE 
     AND "PayDate" BETWEEN '2023-07-01' AND '2023-12-01'
),

active_users AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT "Month", "UserId"
  FROM payments
),

inactive_users AS (
  SELECT a."UserId", a."Month"
  FROM active_users a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM payments b
    WHERE a."UserId" = b."UserId" AND (a."Month" + INTERVAL '1 month') = b."Month"
  )
)

SELECT * FROM inactive_users
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of the CTE active_users AS... why not just use SELECT DISTINCT in the previous CTE?
2. In your final CTE the EXISTS clause should be querying the "public"."Payments" table. At the moment you're querying the active_users table which obviously only has users for the previous month, not the next month

Comment: Merci for answer. I’ve incorporated your suggestions, but it still produces an incorrect list of inactive users.

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the various use cases - and then provide the result you want to see based on that data